# Access struct values inside an interface

Tags: go, struct, interface

I have an interface{} that is similar like -

```
Rows interface{}
```

In the **Rows** interface i put **ProductResponse** struct.

```
type ProductResponse struct {
    CompanyName     string                        `json:"company_name"`
    CompanyID       uint                          `json:"company_id"`
    CompanyProducts []*Products                   `json:"CompanyProducts"`
}
type Products struct {
    Product_ID          uint      `json:"id"`
    Product_Name        string    `json:"product_name"`
}
```

I want to access Product_Name value. How to access this.
I can access  outside values (CompanyName , CompanyID) by using "**reflect**" pkg.

```
value := reflect.ValueOf(response)
CompanyName := value.FieldByName("CompanyName").Interface().(string)
```

I am not able to access **Products** struct values. How to do that?

Comment: Don’t use empty interface too much. Look at “Go proverbs” by Rob Pike

Comment: This is a code smell. Interfaces describe behaviour, not data. A better approach would be to add getter methods to your interface (e.g. `type Rows interface{ CompanyProducts() []*Products }`, and then have your `ProductResponse` struct satisfy that interface (and in the implementation, just return the struct field).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions):

```golang
pr := rows.(ProductResponse)
fmt.Println(pr.CompanyProducts[0].Product_ID)
fmt.Println(pr.CompanyProducts[0].Product_Name)
```

Or you can use the [`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package:

```golang
rv := reflect.ValueOf(rows)

// get the value of the CompanyProducts field
v := rv.FieldByName("CompanyProducts")
// that value is a slice, so use .Index(N) to get the Nth element in that slice
v = v.Index(0)
// the elements are of type *Product so use .Elem() to dereference the pointer and get the struct value
v = v.Elem()

fmt.Println(v.FieldByName("Product_ID").Interface())
fmt.Println(v.FieldByName("Product_Name").Interface())
```

https://play.golang.org/p/RAcCwj843nM

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using reflection you should use type assertion.

```golang
res, ok := response.(ProductResponse) 
if ok { // Successful
   res.CompanyProducts[0].Product_Name // Access Product_Name or Product_ID
} else {
   // Handle type assertion failure 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access `Product_Name` value without even using "reflect" pkg by simply iterating over the `CompanyProducts` slice by using `for` loop.I have created a simple program for you scenario as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type ProductResponse struct {
    CompanyName     string      `json:"company_name"`
    CompanyID       uint        `json:"company_id"`
    CompanyProducts []*Products `json:"CompanyProducts"`
}
type Products struct {
    Product_ID   uint   `json:"id"`
    Product_Name string `json:"product_name"`
}

func main() {

    var rows2 interface{} = ProductResponse{CompanyName: "Zensar", CompanyID: 1001, CompanyProducts: []*Products{{1, "prod1"}, {2, "prod2"}, {3, "prod3"}}}

    for i := 0; i < len(rows2.(ProductResponse).CompanyProducts); i++ {
        fmt.Println(rows2.(ProductResponse).CompanyProducts[i].Product_Name)
    }

}
```

Output:

```
prod1
prod2
prod3
```